# On Click Event for HTML Classes on Div not being called

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, notifications

I am trying to write a send notification function where a notification appears in the top right like OS X notifications do. I'm not using a library to do this and am using jquery as a resource.

I have a container for my notifications called `#notifications`. Which I am appending to when sending a notification to my website

The notifications are sending and stacking nicely as required, however I need to log an onclick event so that they fade out when clicked and any notifications below move up. They all have dynamic id's and there could be an infinite number of notifications on the site at the same time (there never will be, but the principle is there).

I have tried using the `.bind()`, `.click()`, `.live()` and `.on()` but none of them seem to be working.

The way I am using them is like this:

```
$('.notification').bind('click', function()
{
    // CODE HERE
}
```

The notification class is only ever on the surrounding container for the notification like this:

```
<div class="notification"><p>Message here</p></div>
```

Please help me out :)

Comment: You may not have copied it into your question but you need to properly close bind by adding ); after your }

Comment: Yeah I just wrote it so you all could see what I was doing, I did actually have it and it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the element is not yet created when you register the event.

If I understood correctly, you have something like this:

```
<div id="notifications">
    <div id="some-dynamic-id" class="notification"></div>
</div>
```

If that is correct, you should register the event like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#notifications").on("click", ".notification", function() {
        //your code
    });
});
```

I know you have tried `.on()`, but I believe you tried with `$(".notification")`. Note, that here I assumed that `#notifications` already exists when you register the event.

EDIT: `$(function() {}); //do be, or not to be`

The `$(function() {});` part was added around the event definition to handle the possible case that the `#notifications` does not exist when the `.on()` is called. It essentially roans when the document was loaded.

Comment: Does it matter that my `#notifications` doesn't have a height and width and that the `.notification` has a position fixed?

Comment: Btw this is the right solution, I thought class notifactions is the container. And no it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Post your code in jsfiddle and I may try to make it work

Comment: Okay, so this is really confusing it works in jsfiddle but not my website?

https://jsfiddle.net/4qf2ry6t/

Comment: For some reason on my website I had to use `$(document).on('click', '.notification', function(){}` in order for it to work... Done it now

Comment: Zach, this means that the solution is good, but for some reason, at your website's end something prevents it from working. Try to debug your javascript.

Comment: @ZachRoss-Clyne have you tried to wrap your code with `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`?

Comment: @Regent, I have edited my answer. It might be the missing piece of the puzzle.

Comment: @LajosArpad, it will be good to add explanation about why it might be necessary to your answer, even though there already are thousand questions and answers with `document.ready` problem in SO :)

Comment: I have actually fixed it, and provided the answer in this comment thread, waiting for someone to read it and post the answer. I don't like taking the credit when someone could get reputation for it as all the answers are very close to the solution

Comment: @ZachRoss-Clyne, your solution is inferior, you are adding the .on() to the document, so the whole document will be responsible for any notifications inside. It works, but it is clearly inferior to a more specific solution. Please, read my answer carefully: "Note, that here I assumed that #notifications already exists when you register the event." In contrary to my assumption, your #notifications was not existent when you registered the event. The fact that it worked in the fiddle and not at your site should raise a question for you.

Comment: @Regent, I have added a small explanation to help newbies. We have all been there, so it was a valid request.

Comment: @ZachRoss-Clyne if you found solution, it doesn't mean that it is good one. If the problem is in not adding `document.ready`, then `$(document).on('click'` is not optimal solution, because it results in multiple checks for `.notification` during every click in page.

Comment: There is never right and wrong code. There is however code that works and code that doesn't. Given that this question is about my situation and anyone else's who has the same issue, the answers provided are wrong. However, I am in complete agreement that my solution is inferior to a lot of other ways of doing it... Yes I'm checking the page on click every time to see if its a notification, however other answers given don't work. Remember that there is never right and wrong code, the only thing that pulls them apart is elegance. Which I agree mine is not elegant

Answer (score 1):

Do not use bind on notification class, use it on children:

```
$('#notifications').children('.notification').on('click', function() {
    // some stuff
})
$('#notifications').on('click', '.notitfication' function() {
    // this should work too
})
```

Comment: It does not matter, this will select nested divs (it does not have to be div - it can be anything like class, id or any other element for that matter)

Comment: Just given this a go and this doesn't work either :\